# Every time I run my project on android studio, I get the same output on the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've been trying to get the text field on my first android app lately.

Every time I run the project it shows the same output on the emulator.

[image]

Following is the code:

```
package com.example.demoap;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: please upload your code so that you can get help

Comment: have you actually ran your app ?

Comment: Yes, I built and then ran the project.

Answer (score 1):

```
Build > Clean project

Build > Rebuild project
```

then try to run it again.

Or invalidate then do same procedure with clean and rebuild

```
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Comment: I created a new virtual device and this helped in getting the correct output on the emulator

Answer (score 0):

This thing is also in Ionic when you use in windows

My temporary solution

Simplest way I know this is not a good idea but please unistall before run the app in emulator.